# ReactJS – Public/Admin apps with Express

Tags: express, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm currently trying to build a single page application with a separate SPA for admin in ReactJS. I started to build the basic structure (I've watched/read/followed along with 4-5 end to end tutorials), but now I'm confused how to build the admin section of the application as a separate app. How can I get express to serve one app at `admin.localhost:3000` or `localhost:3000/admin`, and the other (public site) at the root? And how would I go about restructuring my project? Currently my Gulp setup has everything in `/app` bundling into the `/public` folder. I think I can figure out how to set up Gulp to bundle up both apps, I just need help with Express and the structure.

Thanks in advance!

**Also, any other advice for building the backend of a ReactJS app would be greatly appreciated – it's not something you see in tutorials often, so I'm unsure if my starting point is valid.**

Below is my `server.js` file in the root directory of my project.

```
var config = require('./config');

// Models
var Show = require('./models/show');
var People = require('./models/people');
var Network = require('./models/network');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect(config.database);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(){
  console.info('Error: Could not connect to MongoDB. Did you forget to run `mongod?');
})

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res) {
  Router.match({ routes: routes.default, location: req.url }, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RoutingContext, renderProps));
      var page = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: html });
      res.status(200).send(page);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Page Not Found')
    }
  });
});

var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Currently, my project is structured like so:

```
.
├── Gulpfile.js
├── app
│   ├── actions
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── alt.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── routes.js
│   ├── stores
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── ...
├── bower.json
├── config.js
├── models
│   ├── ...
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── favicon.png
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── js
│       ├── bundle.js
│       ├── bundle.js.map
│       ├── vendor.bundle.js
│       └── vendor.js
├── server.js
└── views
    └── index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view/page for your admin stuff like you've done with your main page, then can create a new route for '/admin' or whatever you like that returns your admin page..

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
  res.render('your admin page');
});
```

Then add some middleware onto the route to validate admin authentication